# Cannot set a variable in a batch file

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have the following...

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %%p
ECHO ...this worked
ECHO. 
PAUSE

for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do set cpu=%%p
ECHO cpu is %cpu%
ECHO ...this did not work
ECHO. 
PAUSE
```

How come I can't set the number in the variable %cpu% it's always blank!

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name for the re-formatting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do set cpu=%%p & goto :end_for
:end_for
```

`WMIC` produces an empty line at the end.You can try also with `/format:csv` at the end of wmic call which will prevent that.

Check also this: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266

Comment: This worked, thank you very much!  Appreciate the explanation too!

Answer (score 0):

Have not found a solution quite yet but the problem seems to be that

```
wmic cpu get loadpercentage
```

has more than your two lines in the output, the for loop iterates over all lines

if i actually echo all sets in the for loop it looks like this

```
set cpu=1
set cpu=
cpu is
```